# unknown option: {:resynchronize=>false} (ArgumentError) in ..../lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/br idge.rb:17:in `initialize'

Tags: ruby, capybara, selenium-webdriver

I am using Capybara selenium webdriver in my env.rb I have the following code

```
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :ff, :resynchronize => false)
```

when I execute my feature file using cucumber comman
e.g cucumber test.feature

I am getting the below error

> unknown option: {:resynchronize=>false} (ArgumentError)
>         c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.26.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/br
>   idge.rb:17:in `initialize'

I am not sure what causes the issue. When I remove `:resynchronize => false` from the code and have it as below:

```
 Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :ff)
```

The code works but I need to have `resynchronize => false`.

Answer (score 0):

If you read [here](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/commit/a1b1cc7132a2e7a) you will notice that **resynchronization was removed 10 months ago** due to being unstable. If you want to wait for ajax in your tests you could implement a step like this:

```
 When /^I wait (\d+) seconds?$/ do |seconds|
    sleep seconds.to_i
 end
```

And the then call

```
When I wait 5 seconds
Then I click on "link_1"
# and so on
```

Comment: Hi thanks but I get the same error after trying the line, please let me know if you required any other information!

Comment: Okay, Thanks for your suggestions I updated my capybara now it doesnt points to c:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.26.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/firefox/br idge.rb:17:in `initialize' but still it raises the argument error and points to line in my steps where I Vist a URL! unknown option: {:resynchronize=>false} (ArgumentError)
      ./features/step_definitions/steps.rb:38

Comment: hav you tried pasting `Capybara::Selenium::Driver::DEFAULT_OPTIONS[:resynchronize] = false` before you instantiate the driver ?

Comment: thanks again but With the DEFAULT_OPTIONS code update ie. Capybara::Selenium::Driver::DEFAULT_OPTIONS[:resynchronize] = false
# .... somecode
Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, { :browser => :ff }) I still get the same unknown option: {:resynchronize=>false} (ArgumentError) error! One more information the "Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :ff, :resynchronize => false)" code works well in another work system!

Comment: Thank you for you help and time! when I figured it out will post it

Comment: Hey Kai.. I was using capybara 2.0 now I uninstalled it and installed capybara version 1.1.2 then now it works with my very first code Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, :browser => :ff, :resynchronize => false) this is a workaround it got to be working under 2.0 version too!